# Why updating onetomany field makes all other previous filed null in typeorm

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, typescript, typeorm

**src/models/userModel.ts**

```
@Entity()
    export class User extends BaseEntity {
      @PrimaryColumn()
      id: string;
    
      @Column()
      name: string;
    
      @Column()
      phoneNumber: string;
    
      @OneToMany((type) => Token, (token) => token.user)
      tokens: Token[];
    }
    
    @Entity()
    export class Token extends BaseEntity {
      @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
      no: number;
    
      @PrimaryColumn({ length: 900 })
      token: string;
    
      @ManyToOne((type) => User, (user) => user.tokens)
      user: User;
    }
```

**src/index.ts**

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
import { Token, User } from "./models/userModel";
createConnection().then(async (_) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    console.log("Loop number " + i + "\n");
    let user = new User();
    user.id = "test1";
    user.name = "Om";
    user.phoneNumber = "432423";
    let token = new Token();
    token.token = "grgrg3432edsd";
    user.tokens = [token];
    await token.save();
    await user.save();
    (await User.find({ relations: ["tokens"] })).forEach((e) => console.log(e));
  }
});
```

After running `nodemon src/typeorm.ts` output is,

```
Loop number 1

User {
  id: 'test1',
  name: 'Om',
  phoneNumber: '432423',
  tokens: [ Token { no: 1, token: 'grgrg3432edsd' } ]
}
Loop number 2

User {
  id: 'test1',
  name: 'Om',
  phoneNumber: '432423',
  tokens: [ Token { no: 2, token: 'grgrg3432edsd' } ]
}
```

See that in second loop it returns only one Token object instead of all tokens assigned to that user

I did further checked the table using mysql query :-

```
mysql> select * from token;
+----+---------------+--------+
| no | token         | userId |
+----+---------------+--------+
|  1 | grgrg3432edsd | NULL   |
|  2 | grgrg3432edsd | test1  |
+----+---------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can see in first row userId becomes null, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

as you recreate a user with the same id, it's like you updating the entity columns and as you see `user.tokens = [token]` in this line you're like giving a new array of tokens that has the only latest token created,
what I suggest you, create an array of tokens, example:

```
    for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    console.log("Loop number " + i + "\n");
    let user = new User();
    user.id = "test1";
    user.name = "Om";
    user.phoneNumber = "432423";
    let token = new Token();
    token.token = "grgrg3432edsd";
    user.tokens = user.tokens.push(token); // push the new token the list of user's token
    await token.save();
    await user.save();
    (await User.find({ relations: ["tokens"] })).forEach((e) => console.log(e));
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**

to solve your problem you can use push from tokens property:

```
 user.tokens = user.tokens.push(token);
```

Comment: Actually you didn't understand my case here, sorry for being unclear, actually I want to insert into token table for that user, for e.g. if user sign-in from other device then new token gets generated and I want to add it to tokens table without making previous tokens userId null, /n the loop here is just to demonstrate two devices trying to sign-in and thereby getting token added in database

Comment: I got you, you only need to make push from tokens property ( answer updated)

Comment: `push` returns length of array `number` and `user.tokens` is array `Token[]` , sorry I don't get what you want to explain here.

Comment: push function is for adding a new item to a list, So as I added in my answer `user.tokens.push(token);` we add a new token to the array of `token []` as you said

Comment: I'm here for any explanation  you need

Comment: Do you mean to push new token in array of user.token ?, but still there is issue, user.token is undefined which causes error while accessing push method of that object

Answer (score 0):

I think that in must add in `user.tokens = [previousToken, newToken];` all previous token that you have for that user

Comment: I think same, but isn't there any easy way to do these ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
createConnection().then(async (_) => {

      const tokens: Token[] = [];
      for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    
        let token = new Token();
        token.token = "grgrg3432edsd";
        
        const newToken = await token.save(); //this should work if .save() returns the token saved in database
        tokens.push(newToken);
      }
      let user = new User();
      user.id = "test1";
      user.name = "Om";
      user.phoneNumber = "432423";
      user.tokens = tokens;
      await user.save();
      (await User.find({ relations: ["tokens"] })).forEach((e) => console.log(e));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked :-

```
  let User_user = await User.findOne(user);
  user.tokens = User_user?.tokens ?? [];
  user.tokens.push(token);
  user.save();
```

Any more suggestions to make this code bit simpler are welcomed.
Even if you have different approach then please feel free to share.